# What does speed of an object relative to water mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, velocity, relative-motion

A swimmer swims with the velocity 1.25 m/s "relative to water". He has to swim across the river which is 150 meters wide. If his direction of velocity is perpendicular to the stream, he is taken away by the stream 120 meters below. What direction relative to the stream does he have to choose in order to get to the opposite point on the other side? How long will it take him?

My question is what does "relative to water mean"? I am not sure how to imagine it when the water is moving.

**Edit:** Is my interpretation of velocity (relative to something) in these images correct? If not, can you please draw an image where the "velocity of the swimmer relative to water" would be shown? Or at least how do I find out?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Happy new year Lauren, you need to read through the concepts on this page, and related ones, concerning vectors: https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/Lesson-1/Relative-Velocity-and-Riverboat-Problems

Comment: That's a good point ("..So your speed >>relative to the train<< is just that 1mph.."). So the vector of the velocity of the swimmer (relative to water) could actually point anywhere (and it would still be 1.25 m/s)? Is that correct?

Comment: So regardless of where the person on the train is walking, his relative speed to the train is always 1mph. If the person goes forward, backwards, left or anywhere while being on the train the person's relative speed to the train would still be 1mph, right? And if I want to know the person's relative speed to the ground then it would be the sum of the vectors, so if the person goes the same direction as the train it would be 60+1mph=61mph , if the person goes opposite direction it would be 60+(-1)mph=59mph, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the second diagram is wrong, I get it now. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a great question, which brings you to the need of [material derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative) in fluid dynamics, since flow velocity will not only be time dependent, but also position dependent.

Now for the actual question. I believe, it assumes that the flow velocity is homogeneous (the same in every point). With this in mind, it becomes a simple relative velocity problem to solve. For your interpretation for relative velocity, the one for the relative velocity to the ground is correct, but I believe the latter isn't. You could imagine the stream is actually the water, and it's carrying the swimmer with it, hence the relative velocity of the swimmer to the water is also just its relative velocity to the stream.

Comment: Well in the second image i was thinking that the velocity of the swimmer relative to velocity of water/stream would be  velocity of the swimmer minus velocity of water/stream. But when you say that the stream is carrying the swimmer with it my interpretation would not make sence.

Comment: one more question: how can I find the direction/angle (relative to the stream) that the swimmer has to choose in order to get to the opposite point on the other side? I counted the velocity of the stream which is 1 m/s and now I would use basic trigoniometry to find the angle. But i chose the angle between the velocity of the stream and velocity of the swimmer relative to water/ground which resulted in 36,9 degrees but the correct result should be 53,1 which is the angle between the velocity of the swimmer and relative velocity to ground/stream. So why should I choose that angle?

Comment: It may have been a poorly phrased question, with regard to the answer. Could you show your detailed calculations? I got 51.3 degrees with the relative angle of the negative velocity of the stream. I think you do not need to work with velocities at all for the first part, but rather displacement, to get the relative angles.

Comment: @LaurenSin, Your comments suggest that you think the swimmer has only one, true velocity. But, that's not the case. Whenever we say, "velocity _of_ some object," there always is some other, implicit object, and we are talking about the velocity _between_ those things; between the swimmer and the ground, between the swimmer and the water, between the water and the ground. Physics problems often will talk about a "coordinate frame" that is "attached to" some thing. (I.e., we can talk about the velocity of the swimmer in a coordinate frame that is attached to the ground, or...

Comment: ...we can talk about the velocity of the swimmer in a coordinate frame that moves with the water.)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question - " relative to water mean"? I am not sure how to imagine it when the water is moving. "

Imagine a lake with still water and you are rowing a boat. You like to know the speed at which you are moving with respect to water. The row you use and what you see when you are on the boat is your speed with respect to water. If the water starts moving in any direction you may not notice.

It is like you are on a train.. so you consider your speed with respect to the train. If the train is moving at a constant speed you won't even know if it is moving or not.. but with respect to ground you will be.